# How do I acquire an OAuth 2.0 Access Token with the r_ads_gen_automation permission for accessing LinkedIn leads for a company page?

Tags: linkedin-api

My end goal is to register my API to receive notifications of leads generated by LinkedIn for my business's Company Page. The docs [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/ads-leadgen#notifications) say I need to register at https://api.linkedin.com/v2/leadNotificationUrls using the r_ads_ge_automation permission. I'm trying to acquire this type of access token by using a web browser to hit https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id_for_my_application&redirect_uri=https://my.company.net/api/oauth/linkedin&state=Testing12345&scope=r_ads_leadgen_automation, then logging in as a user that is an admin for the respective company page, then acquiring authentication code, and finally requesting an access token.

The problem is that when I try to hit https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization (with the query params above), I get an error response stating "r_ads_leadgen is not authorized for your application". I can't find any kind of application configuration that is supposed to give this permission to my application.

Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions are offered to select Partners only. Have you applied to a Partner Program https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner?

Comment: Thank you Chris. I did fill out an application and had a meeting with an integrations rep. He was very friendly and open with my company about what is possible and not possible. He offered alternative solutions, like integrating with existing third-party partners, but we're not ready to offer partnership to us. It seems LinkedIn is very selective with partnerships at this time. I'm noting this for others who come here looking for answers to this question.